# SQL Get sum of group based on joined table

Tags: sql, sum

I want to get the number of unique codes for a group of customers, like such:

Main table:

```
CustomerID | Group
1000001    | A
1000002    | B
1000003    | A
```

Join Table:

```
CustomerID | UniqueID
1000001    | 1
1000001    | 1
1000002    | 2
1000003    | 3
```

Desired result:

```
Group  | Number of Uniques
A      | 2
B      | 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a pretty simple `group by` and `join` query:

```
select m.group, count(distinct j.uniqueid)
from maintable m join
     jointable j
     on m.customerid = j.customerid
group by m.group;
```